# Undo manager for tableView row delete

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, nsundomanager

Is it possible to implement an `undo manager` when you delete a row in a `tableView`?

I have read about `undo manager` and you have to set the `viewController` as `becomeFirstResponder()`.

The problem is that I am using a `tableView` inside a `collectionViewCell`

How shall I proceed with registering an undo?

I tried the following and it doesn't seem to work

```
    @IBAction func tableButtonUndo(_ sender: Any) {

        print("undo working")
        undoItem()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        indexPathSelected = indexPath.row

        if tableView == ordersTableView {

            print("tap in kitchen table view")


            self.removeItemKitchen()

            ordersTableView.reloadData()

        }
    }

    func removeItemKitchen() {
        orderSingle.orderListFormatted.remove(at: indexPathSelected)
        undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: MyVC(), selector: #selector(self.undoItem), object: nil)
        undoManager?.setActionName("Undo")
    }


    func undoItem() {
        undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: MyVC(), selector: #selector(self.removeItemKitchen), object: nil)
        undoManager?.setActionName("Undo")
        undoManager?.undo()
    }
```

This code should undo the operation, but instead, I get a redo, it deletes the next row.

I would like to recover the deleted row by tapping the undo button

Comment: Shouldn't you be doing `undoManager.undo()` in your `undoItem` function? It looks like you are simply adding another item to the stack to be undone when the user taps the Undo button. Also, you'll need the selector for the undo you registered to call a method that will add the row back to the table.  You'll need a lot more code to do what you want.

Comment: I would read up on how NSUndoManager works here: http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/

Comment: Yes, sorry, I forgot to put that

Comment: Here's an example of the approach you should take: https://macdevelopers.wordpress.com/2014/01/31/undoredo-in-a-cocoa-application-example-to-undoredo-addition-deletion-of-rows-in-a-table-view/  Basically, when you remove the row, you register the undo action, with a selector to a function that will add the object back. You will probably pass the object used to build the table row as well as the index to that function.

Comment: That looks good @wottle. Is there a chance to have this as Swift? I struggle while deciphering Obj-C. Still, thanks for your comment!