# How to do an undo function within a tableviewcell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, undo-redo

I am having troubles getting my undo button working. I'm trying to get it to where if you press the delete button on a tableview cell, the undo can re-enter the cell.

My undo:

```swift
@IBAction func undoBtnWasPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    undoItem()
    undoView.isHidden = true
}

func undoItem() {
    undoManager?.registerUndo(withTarget: GoalCell.self, selector: #selector(removeGoal(atIndexPath:)), object: nil)
    undoManager?.undo()
}
```

My remove:

```swift
@objc func removeGoal(atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) {
    guard let managedContext = appDelegate?.persistentContainer.viewContext else { return }
    managedContext.delete(goals[indexPath.row])
    undoView.isHidden = false

    do {
        try managedContext.save()
        print("Successfully removed goal.")
    } catch {
        debugPrint("Could not save: \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at [nsundomanager](http://nshipster.com/nsundomanager/) you will see that you need to register the undo during the delete.  Also reference [SO undo-manager-for-tableview-row-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41623854/undo-manager-for-tableview-row-delete)

Comment: In Target for selector you are not passing object of `GoalCell`, Pass an object of `Goalcell` or any other object where you want to trigger `removeGoal`.

Answer (score 1):

You can just save the data from the datasource of the deleted cell in a property or an array and if the undo button is pressed, you re-add the data into the datasource and reload the row or the full data of the tableview.

**EDIT**

So for instance, in your example you had the delete function delete data from core data based on `goals[indexPath.row]`
Before deleting, save the content from `goals[indexPath.row]` into a separate array.
When undo is tapped, just grab the value from the separate array and add it back to `goals` and add it back into core data.

Then just do a `tableview.reloadData()`

**EDIT 2:**

```
let dataSource: [CustomObject] = [Object1, Object2, Object3]
var undoSource: [CustomObject] = []

func removeRow(indexPath) {
    let object = dataSource[indexPath.row]
    undoSource.append(object)
    dataSource.remove(object)
}

func undo() {
    for object in undoSource {
        dataSource.append(object)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: How would I do this? Undoing is new to me.

Comment: @Z.Smouse added more to the answer

Comment: Do I add like:
let save : goals[indexpath.row] = [indexpath]?

Comment: @Z.Smouse added an example. Please take a close look at the logic and try to apply to your case. There are several other ways to accomplish this, this is a quick and easy way